# What is the purpose of writing a seemingly self-referential "-d . " in the command line interface

Tags: java, command-line-interface

When compiling an application in the command line interface, I sometimes see a command written as follows:

```
javac -d . HelloWorld.java
```

I understand that:

1. `-d <directory>` = Specify where to place generated class files
2. `.` = the current folder

My question is: what is the purpose of writing `-d .`?

It seems self-referential and completely redundant/unnecessary. I would expect simply the following, which to my knowledge has the same effect and is less verbose:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

Is there something that I am missing?

I have used symbolhound.com to search the web for this specific phrase, but could not find any explanation.

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/socketfactory/index.html) on the Oracle Java site does it, for instance:

> ```
> javac -d . XorInputStream.java
> javac -d . XorOutputStream.java
> javac -d . XorSocket.java
> javac -d . XorServerSocket.java
> javac -d . XorServerSocketFactory.java
> javac -d . XorClientSocketFactory.java
> javac -d . Hello.java
> javac -d . HelloClient.java
> javac -d . HelloImpl.java
> ```

Comment: Did you try `man` or `help` ?

Comment: *"Note: an example of usage can be found on this page"* Rather than just linking the page, **show** the usage examples on it in the question. (I've done it for you this time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**WHEN THE SOURCE DIR IS NOT THE CURRENT DIR**

Suppose you have a `Hello.java` file in `/tmp/src`

When you are in `/tmp`, compiling with

```
javac -d . src/Hello.java
```

puts the class file in the *current* directory, so it is `/tmp/Hello.class`.

Without the option, it goes to the same directory as the source file, that is `/tmp/src/Hello.class`.

**MOREOVER** there is a difference when **packages** are involved. Compiling this code

```
package Foo;

public class Hello  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
}
```

from the `/tmp/src` directory with the `-d .` option builds a subdirectory for the package

```
/tmp/src
├── Foo
│   └── Hello.class
└── Hello.java
```

whereas `javac Hello.java` leaves the class file in the current directory

```
$ tree
.
└── Hello.java

0 directories, 1 file
$ javac Hello.java 
$ tree
.
├── Hello.class
└── Hello.java

0 directories, 2 files
```

No animal was hurt during the test with javac 1.8.0_101.